# How to hide SubTotal Column if the month is not full solar Month in a range of dates

Tags: reporting-services

In a CashFlow Report I created a tablix with TransactionDate column that is filled with a range of @stardate and @enddate parameters. If the user selects for example:

@stardate='2020-01-01'
@enddate='2020-03-02'

I need to create dynamicaly the month subtotal, but only if the month is full solar month (days from 1 to 31) in the selected range. In the image sample the subtotal of January and February must be visible and the subtotal of March must be hidden.
Any suggestions?

Thanks
Hawa

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/womA8.png)

Comment: what if the start date was say '2020-01-15' (15th January) then do you not show that month either? Is it safe to assume that if the start date is not the beggining of the month and end date is not end of the month, then that months subtotal should not be displayed?

Comment: If the range @startdate-@enddate is not a full solar month, the subtotal column must be hidden. Yes if the star date is '2020-01-15' only the subtotal column must be hidden, the month January and all the columns from 15th January to 31th January must be visible. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: A few questions. 1:Do you have a date table to use?  2. Are you able to make changes to your dataset query or not?

Comment: 1. No; 2.Yes. I tried to create a dataset, but can't figure out how to hide if the month is not in the list of the resultset, may be I'm using wrong expressions in the property column visibility. Thanks. Hawa

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is create a table that contains dates. There are lots of examples out there on how to do this such as this

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

Assuming you now have a dates table with at least the following data available

```
TheDate    TheMonth    TheYear
2020-01-01        1       2020
2020-01-02        1       2020
...
2020-01-31        1       2020
2020-02-01        2       2020
...
2020-12-31       12       2020
...
```

and so on...

You can now get a simple list of last dates of the month

```
CREATE VIEW LastMonthDates AS
SELECT TheYear, TheMonth, MAX(TheDate) AS LastDate
FROM myDatesTable
GROUP BY TheYear, TheMonth
```

This will give us

```
TheYear    TheMonth    LastDate
2020              1  2020-01-31
2020              2  2020-02-29
...
```

and so on.

If you join this to your main data and add the `LastDate` column to your dataset query results, so the results are something like

```
Cluster1    Cluster2    TransDate    Amount    LastDate
Ins         ROW1        2020-02-28   221.35    2020-02-29
```

Your topmost column group hidden property would then be something like

```
=MAX(Fields!TransDate.Value, "MonthColumGroup") <> FIRST(Fields!LastDate.Value, "MonthColumGroup")
```

So, if the highest date within the month group is not the same as the lastdate columne within the same monthgroup then hidden will be `True`

Change `"MonthColumGroup"` to the actual name of your outer month group, it has to be in quotes and is case sensitive.

If you have problems doing this (the grouping could cause issues) You could do that same thing in your dataset query by extend the it to have a column that does the same kind of test and simply sets it 1 or 0 depending on whether the month is complete or not.